# installing react datepicker fails on build of webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-loader, react-datepicker

In trying to install react-datepicker, I came across the import of css through webpack. I cannot get this installed correctly.

Here is my webpack.config.js:
    const path = require('path');

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I installed css-loader with npm. I added the use call above that has style-loader and css-loader, but it failed when I went to load. Anyone have specific installation instructions for the import css into js?
The [react-datepicker instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) are short and vague.

For the react community I just added, most of the date components have this style of import css from javascript file. I am not using create-react-app, I rolled my own, have you been able to get these imports to work in a roll your own webpack environment?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/546). I basically just needed to make sure css-loader and style-loader were installed and add in the following webpack configurations.